# Running board dimensions

Tags: electrical, wiring

I need to install a running board on which to attached some cables going perpendicular to joists.  Is there a minimum size that one should use? I'm planning on installing some 6x1"s.

Comment: You can use a running board if you like, but I don't think it is required. You can staple them directly to the top of the ceiling joists. If you still chose to use a running board, use screws, the vibration of driving nails may loosen the hold the drywall or plaster has to the ceiling

Comment: It IS required if the cables run perpendicular to the joists.

Comment: @Jack Maybe I missed it, but I don't think the OP said anything about being on top of the joists.

Comment: @Tester101, Maybe I am not familiar with the terminology. I see a running board as a VERY narrow catwalk, on top of the joists, I have seen them in a lot of old houses. In all my 42 years of experience, I have never see wires attached to a running board or anything else for that matter to aid in the support of line voltage running exposed in an accessible attic perpendicular to the joists. I am making the large assumption it is in the attic. Other than that, the only requirement was to be stapled every 4' or less and within 6" or a foot of a box or fixture.

Comment: @Jack Running boards can also be used in a basement, to run cables along the bottoms of joists. Also, if the attic has permanent stairs or ladder, any cables run across joists have to be protected. This is commonly accomplished by affixing furring strips on each side of the cable.

Comment: I know this may be getting a little deeper than the OP had figured, but this leads to a curious question. If a 1X6 is needed to support the cables that are run perpendicular to the joists, how does the cables running through drilled joists fare in all of this? I am referring to joists that are not covered by a finish on one side on the other. Last curiosity, is this a code that just come onto the books?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a basement, 14, 12, and I believe 10 cable are required to either be on a running board or drilled through the joists if they are running perpendicular to the joists.  Larger and smaller cable is not required to be on a running board.  I believe this was done because people were using normal cable for receptacles and lighting as clotheslines in the basement.  Keep in mind codes have changed over the years and just because it was legal when the electrician installed ungrounded cable in an asbestos jacket in the 50s doesn't mean it's legal to install it today.  The existing construction can remain, because it was built to the code at the time (assumingly), but if it falls into the scope of your project the only way you're going to pass an inspection for a permit is if you bring it up to code.

Also, if you drill a hole through a joist, make sure you drill in the center of the joist.  This is because the joists are beams supporting a vertical load.  Think of when you see a board with a heavy load, sagging in the middle. This displays compression on top and tension (pulling) on the bottom.  In the very middle, where the board transitions from compression to tension, there is no load, so drilling a hole in the middle will have minimal structural effect.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming.

Comment: This does not answer the question of "**what size** running board should I use" at all.